# Required field validators in ASP.NET

Tags: validation, field, required

I have AJAX tab container with three tabs in it and in third tab, I have a button, which causes validation. When I click on that, I will get a validation summary and required feilds will be showing with a "*"(asterisk). Now, after clicking the button if I want to see all the required fields and moving to first tab and I am not been able to view the "*" (asterisk) marks because page reloads on the tab change.

Please suggest guys, what can I do to show the required field validators even if I change my tab.

Comment: why is that your tab change reloads the page...do you happen to have a tab change event wired up?

Comment: I have few common fields which will automatically capture data according to the tab index.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have OnTabChange event on every tab change this means a postback happens every time you change the tab...however one way to make sure that the fields are validated on tab change is to call `Page.Validate()` in you tab change event...this will make sure that all validation controls on your page are invoked to run their respective validation when the tab is changed...

However, I am just curious as to why you have the postback thing on every tab change...but this is a quick dirty way of doing it.

Comment: Yes.. I have tried the solution which you have given. But here one more problem, I should get the required field validators should show once the button clicked. Here even in after initial page load, if I try to change the tab also I am getting these validators. Please correct me if I am doing something wrong.